# Error during installation of Cairo package on Red Hat (RHEL)

Tags: package, redhat, cairo, rhel

I am working on R and I need to install the `Cairo` package.

```
install.packages("Cairo")
```

**Specification** 
R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)
OS : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.1 (Santiago)

I'm getting following error message:

```
xlib-backend.c:34:74: fatal error: X11/Intrinsic.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [xlib-backend.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Cairo’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib64/R/library/Cairo’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpqtvjPA/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making packages.html  ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("Cairo") :
  installation of package ‘Cairo’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 6):

Had same error. To solve:

Ran the 3 following pieces which were already installed, but doesn't hurt to run and check

```
yum install libX11
yum install libX11-devel
yum install libXt
```

Then ran the following which fixed my problem:

```
yum install libXt-devel
```

Was able to install.packages("Cairo") afterwards in R 2.15.0 RHEL6.1

Comment: Just had the issue on Debian, for me the missing package was libxt-dev

Answer (score 1):

On Alpine-linux I fixed this using the following:

```
apk add cairo-dev
```